# ¿Cómo puedo guardar un archivo CSV con el nombre de un contador en python?

Tags: python, bucle-for, csv, twitter, twitter-api

Estoy implementando búsquedas en un librería de Python que se llama `twint` lo quiero hacer para una lista de ciudades, esto lo hago en un ciclo.
Siguiendo la idea de este post https://www.kaggle.com/discussion/207512 genero una función para llevar a cabo la búsqueda.

Del código se puede decir que *all_cities_mexico* es una lista con el nombre de las ciudades más grandes de México.
Necesito generar los archivos CSV con el nombre de mi contador, en este caso `city`, esta es mi propuesta pero no genera ningún archivo y dice que encontró 0 tweets.

```
def scrape_by_city(keywords, since, until):
    unique_cities=set(all_cities_mexico) #To get unique cities of country
    cities = sorted(unique_cities) #Sort & convert datatype to list
    for city in cities:
        print(city)
        c = twint.Config()
        c.Search = keywords #search keyword
        c.Since = since
        c.Until = until
        c.Store_csv = True
        c.Output = 'C:/Users/Manager/' + city
        c.Near = city
        c.Hide_output = True
        c.Count = True
        c.Stats = True
        c.Resume = 'resume.txt'
        twint.run.Search(c)
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, por favor.

Comment: He montado un ejemplo tomando las 6 ciudades más grandes de México y funciona correctamente. ¿Qué rangos de fechas estás usando? Por otro lado, si twint no devuelve tweets no escribe ningún archivo, por lo que está funcionando correctamente si no te está encontrando ningún tweet

Comment: Gracias por el aporte.